# Mayavi visualizing huge 3D arrays

Tags: 3d, large-data-volumes, mayavi

I have a 3D dataset with around 6 million points. Is there any way to plot it using contour3D? Every time tried, mayavi goes out of memory.

Else, is there a way to increase the number of colors in the volume() ctf to more than 256 colors. I have floating point data values and have to discretise them to use the Volume(). Hence, I lose a lot of imformation. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with the tools you are describing, but with large datasets and charts so I will give you one idea on how we tackle a similar problem.

Suppose you get a data sample from a temperature sensor every second for 1 year, these are 31M+ records... you don't have the "space" available to draw, let say, 1 pixel for each sample. What you can do is get an average value for each pixel to be rendered. Let say you have 800px width on the screen and 31M+ samples, just slice the samples 800 times and get the average (representative) values for each slice/pixel. If you need more resolution, just "zoom" into the range and again, get the values.. and so on until you only have 800 samples to draw.

Hope this help and sorry about my english.